# Replace all the ocurrence of a string (Keep the uppercase and lowercase words) Javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, split

I'm trying to replace all the occurrence of a word in a string, the first problem that I had was to replace a uppercase word or lowercase work (fixed with a regular expression), however I need to replace that word for the same word adding some HTML tags, I was able to do it, but when I replace them does not keep the uppercase or lowercase letter. like this:

```
var string = "Hello, hello, HELLO";
search = "hello";
replacement = "<h1>hello</h1>";    
string.split(new RegExp(search,"i")).join(replacement);
```

And I get this:

```
<h1>hello<h1>, <h1>hello<h1>, <h1>hello<h1>
```

However I need to maintain the uppercase or lowercase. I need something like this:

```
<h1>Hello<h1>, <h1>hello<h1>, <h1>HELLO<h1>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string.replace(new RegExp('(' + search + ')',"ig"), '<h1>$1</h1>');
```

You can do something like that.

Comment: Perfect! This is what i needed! what is $1? can you explain me?

Comment: The $1 is a reference to the first regex capture group in the regular expression. In this case your regex `/(hello)/ig` has one capture group (denoted by the parentheses) for hello. When you reference $1 you are referencing whatever text matched that capture group. Which will be your original text.